# How do you set a relative path for a file-based package source with NuGet?

Tags: nuget

I'm using NuGet 2.1 with multiple solutions, each in a child directory under a single parent directory and a single packages directory which is shared by all the solutions (this became possible with NuGet 2.1).

I'd like to add a file-based package source which points to the packages directory in my working copy (I'm using Subversion).

This works:

```
<configuration>
  <repositoryPath>_Packages</repositoryPath>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="Working copy package source" value="C:\AllMySolutions\_Packages" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

This doesn't:

```
<configuration>
  <repositoryPath>_Packages</repositoryPath>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="Working copy package source" value="_Packages" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

I don't want to hard-code the absolute path but can't find a way of using a relative path in the value attribute inside `activePackageSource`.

Comment: I've not had any responses here so I've created an issue on the NuGet issue tracker: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2753

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It looks like this is now supported.

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2810

1. Put a file called nuget.config in the root of your solution (next to packages folder and solution file) containing:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <packageSources>
       <add key="Local" value="packages-local" />
     </packageSources>
   </configuration>
   ```
2. Build you packages to the packages-local folder.
3. The packages in this folder will be available to add to other projects in the solution. (You may need to restart VS or at least close-reopen your solution for the config to be picked up).

Comment: Visual Studio (2019) seems to lose these settings if you try to modify them via GUI. Renamed a source via "Manage NuGet packages for Solution" menu, and what got written in the `nuget.config` was just empty `<configuration>` node.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem with `<repositoryPath>`. I needed to force all SOLUTIONs in my git repository to use same folder to store their NuGet packages. So I created a `nuget.config` file on the root of the repository with the following contents, as it was described in [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="NugetPackages\" />
    </config>
</configuration>
```

After manually creating `NugetPackages` beside `nuget.config` and installing packages, there was nothing in that directory, but everything was working fine. Then I found that VS has created `C:\NugetPackages` and moved packages there. After trial and error for a while, at last the relative path using `.\` worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value=".\NugetPackages\" />
    </config>
</configuration>
```

I hope it behaves the same for other configurations as well.

**P.S.:** As Matthew already said, I had to restart VS to make my edits in `nuget.config` take effect.

Answer (score 1):

For .NETCore/.NET5 and newer, the config key `repositoryPath` doesn't work anymore, and it is now named `globalPackagesFolder`, so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value=".\packages\" />
    </config>
</configuration>
```